# SASS - select headlines of class

Tags: sass

I want to give headlines icons (background-image) like this:

```
.icon_girl {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, ... SVG code ...');
}
```

Now I want to give H1, H2, H3 etc. different sizes. I tried:

```
.icon_girl {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, ... SVG code ...');

    &h1 {
        background-size: 37px;
        padding-left: 48px;
    }

    &h2 {
        background-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 38px;
    }
}
```

But this, for sure, isn't working. But maybe you know what I want to achive. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get this kind of selector `h1.icon_girl` you have to use interpolation and `@at-root` directive to extract the current selector from root selector in which it's nested.

**SASS**

```
.icon_girl {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, ... SVG code ...');

    @at-root h1#{&}  {
        background-size: 37px;
        padding-left: 48px;
    }

    @at-root h2#{&}  {
        background-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 38px;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
.icon_girl {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8, ... SVG code ...");
}
h1.icon_girl {
  background-size: 37px;
  padding-left: 48px;
}
h2.icon_girl {
  background-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 38px;
}
```

Comment: This works perfect, thank you, I think I can use this a lot in future. In this case I ended up using "em" so the paddings and background-sizes always fit to the font-size of the headlines.